# Upper bound on $ \sum_{n=1}^N\sqrt{\ln(n)} $

Tags: inequality

I was wondering if there exist some upper bound on the sum: $$ \sum_{n=1}^N\sqrt{\ln(n)} $$
I would like to obtain something like: $$ \sum_{n=1}^N\sqrt{\ln(n)} \le \sqrt{C N\log(N)} $$
for some constant C. Clearly I have: $ \sum_{n=1}^N\ln(n) \le N\log(N) $, but I don't know what happens with the $\sqrt{} $..

Comment: sth like $N \sqrt{\ln(N)}$ ?

Comment: No, I would like to have N under the sqare root, I don't know if such a bound exists..

Comment: @Physor it's a proof that what OP wants to obtain is unobtainable. There is no upper bound of the type OP wants.

Comment: Physor obtained $\displaystyle \sum_{n\le N} \sqrt{\log n}\ll N\sqrt{\log N}$ and by partial summation and Stirling formula $\displaystyle \log n!\sim n\log n$ we have $$\sum_{n\le N}\sqrt{\log n}=\sum_{n\le N}\log n\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\gg \left(\sum_{n\le N}\log n\right)\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\log N}} \sim N\sqrt{\log N}$$ Hence, weaker than Unit, $\displaystyle  \sum_{n\le N} \sqrt{\log n}  \asymp N\sqrt{\log N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\sqrt{\log n}>\sum_{N/2}^N\sqrt{\log n}>(N/2)\sqrt{\log(N/2)}>\sqrt{CN\log N}$$ for $N>N_0(C)$.

Comment: No, @Physor, it's a proof that the kind of upper bound OP wants, doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

I shall show that the sum in question is asymptotic to $N\sqrt{\log N}$ for large $N$. In particular, there is no such bound. By the Euler$-$Maclaurin formula,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\sqrt {\log n} }  = \int_1^N {\sqrt {\log t} \,\mathrm{d}t}  + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt {\log N} ).
$$
By L'Hôpital's rule
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \frac{{\int_1^N {\sqrt {\log t} \,\mathrm{d}t} }}{{N\sqrt {\log N} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \cfrac{{\sqrt {\log N} }}{{\sqrt {\log N}  + \cfrac{1}{{2\sqrt {\log N} }}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \cfrac{1}{{1 + \cfrac{1}{{2\log N}}}} = 1.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\sqrt {\log n} }  \sim N\sqrt {\log N} 
$$
as $N \to  + \infty$.

Comment: Nice! This approach is more general than mine. +1!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $$\sum_{n=1}^N \sqrt{\log n} \sim N \sqrt{\log N} \qquad (N \to \infty). \tag{*}$$
The upper bound $N\sqrt{\log N}$ has already been pointed out by Physor in the comments. As for a lower bound: note that in the range $N^\delta \le n \le N$, we have $\sqrt{\log n} \ge \sqrt{\delta} \sqrt{\log N}$. Since there are $(N - N^\delta) \sim N$ terms in this range, we get that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sqrt{\log n} \ \gtrsim \sqrt{\delta} N \sqrt{\log N} \qquad (N \to \infty).$$
Taking $\delta \to 1^-$ yields (*).